# Postgresql9-4 - User define function that uses a join - ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

I am venturing into pg/sql for the first time and I wrote this function that (attempts) to return results from a query that uses a JOIN.

The query works when I run on it self.  However, when it is running within the function I wrote it complains about a missing "FROM". I also used table aliases hoping that it may fix the problem but it did not.

I am getting information from the following tables and rows.

```
  TABLE                |    ROW
 ---------------------------------------
 banned_users         |    banned_lcl_account
 ---------------------------------------
 rhost_active_users   |    active_users
```

Here is the error when I run my function

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "a_u"
LINE 1: SELECT LOOP_V.a_u.ipaddress
```

And here is the function I wrote.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_BANNED_ACTIVE_USERS()
RETURNS TABLE 
(
SRC_HOST TEXT,
DST_HOST TEXT
)
AS $$
DECLARE 
   LOOP_V RECORD;

BEGIN
    FOR LOOP_V IN ( 
    select 
    b_u.banned_lcl_account,
    a_u.ipaddress,
    a_u.hostip,
    date_trunc ('second', a_u.time_captured)
    from  banned_users as b_u
    inner join  rhost_active_users  as a_u
    on b_u.banned_lcl_account = a_u.active_users 
    and   a_u.hostip <>  'TTY Login' 
    or    a_u.hostip <>  'Local PTS Login'
    )

LOOP
SRC_HOST := LOOP_V.a_u.ipaddress;
DST_HOST := LOOP_V.a_u.hostip;

END LOOP;
END; $$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
--select CHECK_BANNED_ACCOUNTS()
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is this:

```
SRC_HOST := LOOP_V.a_u.ipaddress;
DST_HOST := LOOP_V.a_u.hostip;
```

The record that is used for the loop variable only contains column names, not their table aliases. So the record only has the fields: `ipaddress` and `hostip`. So your immediate problem can be fixed using:

```
SRC_HOST := LOOP_V.ipaddress;
DST_HOST := LOOP_V.hostip;
```

However the whole function is overly complex. You don't need the loop nor do you need PL/pgSQL. This can be written as a simple SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_BANNED_ACTIVE_USERS()
RETURNS TABLE (SRC_HOST TEXT,DST_HOST TEXT)
AS $$
    select a_u.ipaddress,
           a_u.hostip,
    from  banned_users as b_u
      join rhost_active_users as a_u
       on b_u.banned_lcl_account = a_u.active_users 
      and (a_u.hostip <>  'TTY Login' or a_u.hostip <>  'Local PTS Login')

$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Note that I also removed the unused columns from the SELECT statement in order to match the function's signature of returning two columns

---

Some additional notes:

> --select CHECK_BANNED_ACCOUNTS()

This is wrong, you need to use a set returning function like a table:

```
select *
from CHECK_BANNED_ACCOUNTS();
```

And finally:

> LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

The language name is an identifier, do not enclose it in single quotes:

```
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

or

```
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) 

So it seems I have a conceptual problem when it comes to deciding when to use functions and in which way.

Could you suggest a book that talks about pg/sql in a manner that puts things in context. So far all the material that I have read do not offer a context, just dry examples.

Comment: http://postgres.cz/wiki/PL/pgSQL_%28en%29 - there is simple rule, you should to minimize number of executed SQL statement - what is possible do with one **readable** SQL you should to do by one SQL. Using SQL inside `LOOP` should be corner case - security, readability, current API...